# Universal Analytics: Multiple inline OnClick events triggered by single click

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to trigger multiple inline OnClick events on a single click.

The first (window.open) triggers a Facebook share dialog box. This fires properly.

The second `{ga(...) }` should trigger an event goal in Google (Universal) Analytics. However, this second OnClick event does not work properly and the goal is not being recorded in GA.

```
<a 
class="facebook-share" 
href="#" 
onclick="
   window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
   'facebook-share-dialog', 
   'width=626,height=436'); 
   return false; 
   ga('send', 'event', 'social share', 'facebook share', 'top button' );
"> 
   Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Any idea how to fix such that the FB share dialog still fires, and the click is also tracked in GA?

Comment: Untested, so a comment rather than an answer, but can't you track the event first and then open FB with a hit callback function (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `return false` between calls, so handler exits before the second call. Place it after the call to `ga()` function.

Comment: No problem :) we all learn something new every day. Please mark answer as accepted if the solution was useful.